# Running into contrasts/factors need to have 2 or more levels issue despite variable validity?

Tags: r, regression, glm, survey, r-factor

Trying to generate a quasibinomial survey glm in "survey" package--have cleaned all data/set missing values to NA (recommended in some threads although others say that svyglm autodrops?), dependent variable is binomial but keep getting error: "Error in contrasts<-(*tmp*, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels".  Relevant code:

```
    nsduh.design <-  svydesign(
    id= ~verep,
    strata= ~vestr,
    weights= ~newanalwt, 
    data = nsduh20022020,
    nest = TRUE,
    survey.lonely.psu = "adjust")

    grskltrymodel <- svyglm(grskltry~lsdyr+year+age2+
                            irsex+eduhighcat,
                 design = nsduh.design,
                 family = quasibinomial)
```

Have also ran:

```
    which(sapply(nsduh20022020, function(x) (is.character(x) | is.factor(x)) & length(unique(x))<2))
```

to make sure all variables in the frame meet criteria and none of them return/they have two or more factors (I set them all to factors as well).

I did modify code graciously provided below in an attempt to make a reproducible example:

```
    library(haven)
    library(survey)

#import 2020 data

tf <- tempfile()
download.file( "https://www.datafiles.samhsa.gov/sites/default/files/field-uploads-protected/studies/NSDUH-2020/NSDUH-2020-datasets/NSDUH-2020-DS0001/NSDUH-2020-DS0001-bundles-with-study-info/NSDUH-2020-DS0001-bndl-data-stata_v1.zip" , tf , mode = 'wb' )
w <- unzip( tf , exdir = tempdir() )
x <- read_dta( grep( 'dta$' , w , value = TRUE , ignore.case = TRUE ) )
names( x ) <- tolower( names( x ) )

#import 2019 data

download.file( "https://www.datafiles.samhsa.gov/sites/default/files/field-uploads-protected/studies/NSDUH-2019/NSDUH-2019-datasets/NSDUH-2019-DS0001/NSDUH-2019-DS0001-bundles-with-study-info/NSDUH-2019-DS0001-bndl-data-stata.zip" , tf , mode = 'wb' )
y <- unzip( tf , exdir = tempdir() )
z <- read_dta( grep( 'dta$' , y , value = TRUE , ignore.case = TRUE ) )
names( z ) <- tolower( names( z ) )

x$year = 2020
z$year = 2019

colnames(x)[colnames(x) == "analwtq1q4_c"] <- "analwt_c"
colnames(x)[colnames(x) == "vestrq1q4_c"] <- "vestr"

keep <- c("year", "verep", "vestr", "catage", "grsklsdtry", "lsdflag", "lsdyr",
      "age2", "analwt_c", "eduhighcat", "irsex")

nsduh2020keep <- x[,keep]
nsduh2019keep <- z[,keep]

nsduh2019and2020 = rbind(nsduh2020keep, nsduh2019keep)

nsduh2019and2020$newanalwt = nsduh2019and2020$analwt_c/2


nsduh.design <-  svydesign(
  id= ~verep,
  strata= ~vestr,
  weights= ~newanalwt, 
  data = nsduh2019and2020,
  nest = TRUE,
  survey.lonely.psu = "adjust")

# glm model

grskltrymodel <- svyglm(grsklsdtry~lsdyr+year+age2+
                      irsex+eduhighcat,
                    design = nsduh.design,
                    family = quasibinomial)
```

But this works :-|. Will continue to work on providing a functional example....

Comment: `svyglm()` drops all units with any missing data in any of the variables in the model. It might be that after dropping the missing values, some factor/character variables only have one unique value. Run your check again after running `na.omit()` on a version of your dataset that contains only the variables used in the model.

Comment: I thought of that yes, and I checked (I had already subset the variables I wanted in Stata prior to importing them in)--am going to check again though.

Answer (score 0):

not an answer but could you edit your question with a minimal reproducible example?  maybe modify this code below to edit your question so others can see what you're seeing to help you debug?  :-)  thanks!

```
library(haven)
library(survey)

# download & import 2020
tf <- tempfile()
download.file( "https://www.datafiles.samhsa.gov/sites/default/files/field-uploads-protected/studies/NSDUH-2020/NSDUH-2020-datasets/NSDUH-2020-DS0001/NSDUH-2020-DS0001-bundles-with-study-info/NSDUH-2020-DS0001-bndl-data-stata_v1.zip" , tf , mode = 'wb' )
w <- unzip( tf , exdir = tempdir() )
x <- read_dta( grep( 'dta$' , w , value = TRUE , ignore.case = TRUE ) )
names( x ) <- tolower( names( x ) )


nsduh.design <-  svydesign(
id= ~verep,
strata= ~vestrq1q4_c,
weights= ~analwtq1q4_c, 
data = x,
nest = TRUE,
survey.lonely.psu = "adjust")

# ?
grskltrymodel <- svyglm(grskltry~lsdyr+year+age2+
                        irsex+eduhighcat,
             design = nsduh.design,
             family = quasibinomial)
```

Comment: I actually merged prior years and respective survey weights before setting up the glm (2002-2020), I also subset the variables I needed in Stata prior to loading the files in because RStudio would crash trying to handle the 2002-2019 set otherwise. I can go ahead and post my full code if that helps.

Comment: @MelissaBradley hi!  perhaps parse it into a *minimal reproducible example* ?  stacking twenty years of data probably isn't necessary for you to reproduce the error, and switching between R and stata definitely isn't..  please re-create the error from only the ten lines that i've provided above?  it'll make helping you and debugging your code much easier  :-)

Comment: (Thanks--I'm new to troubleshooting, I understand now, will do. Sorry for the miscommunication!)

Comment: I'm actually getting a different code from your code that I haven't run into yet when I run it:
          "Error in svyglm.survey.design(grskltry ~ lsdyr + year + age2 + irsex +  : 
  all variables must be in design= argument". Not sure how to change this/what to switch around to stop getting that and get my error....

Comment: `grskltry` isn't in the 2020 dataset, not sure about the others.  maybe take a look at your much longer script and see if you can re-create the variables the same way on this easier-to-reproduce example survey design  :-)

Comment: Ooh. I pulled year from svyglm (I made a dummy variable for 2020 and year was already a variable for the other years). Pulling year made the model work, but I need year in my model. The problem is if I set a dummy year to just 2020 for purposes of this example it's going to read as a single factor variable and it won't work. Would you be able to set your code up to read in two years worth of survey data from the site? I could definitely rewrite for a reproducible model with that (I am also going to try doing this too, it might be faster for you to do on your end lol).

Comment: Lol oh wow. I just rewrote combining multiple years in (2019 and 2020) for a reproducible example (question updated with code) and it worked, which makes absolutely no sense because nothing has been functionally modified. Maybe it's the combined dataset vs. individual years...? Idk.

Comment: maybe keep adding years to your minimal reproducible example until you hit the problem, at which point remove the years that did not cause the problem?  that might be the quickest way to narrow it down and also help others help you  :-)

Comment: ^^I was thinking about rewriting anyway since the individual years actually work (and I love the code you added that allows for the files to be directly loaded in via the URL). I will update soon--thank you so so much for your help Anthony, it's been really appreciated!! :)

Comment: Ahhh--"eduhighcat" is the culprit (no entries pre-2015. I have been staring at the problem the whole time). I found the 2015 crosswalk, I bet if I find/merge a compatible pre-2015 changes variable it will fix the issue. Sorry for all the trouble!